# C2664 error stream.write unsigned char *

Tags: visual-c++, iostream

```
ostream &stream;
stream.write(SomeUnsignedCharStar, intSize);
```

error C2664 cannot convert parameter 1 from const unsigned char * to const char *

Is there an overload write for const unsigned char *?
I do not want to change SomeUnsignedCharStar because it is everywhere in the legacy code I inherited.  This was compiled on VC6 with no complain. I am slowly upgrading the code to VS2003 and then VS2010 evantually.

What is the easiest and cleanest fix?

Comment: I wouldn't bother upgrading to VC++ 2003 first, just go straight to the latest.  Visual Studio .NET 2003 was possibly the buggiest version ever.

Comment: I did go straight to VS2010 and all hell broke loose. There are just too many things to take care of in the conversion from VC6 to VS2010.  I tried conversion to VS2008 first and all work out pretty good. All projects built in VS2008. Conversion from VS2008 to VS2010 is much easier being a smaller step. It is not without issue though.

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable.  I'm just advising against messing with VC++ 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast this without any issues.  Strict aliasing allows casting pointers between unsigned and signed versions of the same type, as well as casting from any type to `const char*`, so you're safe here.